printing using a TSC printer with Ionic/Capacitor
We have a TSC printer (TE210) we want to do silent label printing with. Our app is built with capacitor, and we couldn't find a plugin that helps with that yet; all printer plugins open the default android print interface, and we hope to avoid that step.
Now as to our current understanding, our options are either creating our own plugin with the official Android sdk or using some hack someone has already found/built.
First of all, does anybody know of such a hack by chance?
In case we have to build it ourselves, the sdk comes as a jar file, Is it possible to use those for building a capacitor plugin?
Is there any other solution we might be missing here? Maybe a more elegant or practical solution for this?
thanks

There doesn't seem to be a plugin yet. You will therefore have to create your own plugin. You can find the Android and iOS SDK on the TSC website.
